# IndoorAtlas SDK 2.0 maps not loading

Tags: java, android, location, maps, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to use IndoorAtlas in my project. I created `Activity`[this](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/imageview/ImageViewActivity.java) example, but when I start `Activity`, I see nothing, map doesn't loading into `ImageView` and LogCat shows only few lines. Please, help.

My LogCat with "IndoorAtlas" filter:

```
D/IndoorAtlasActivity: onCreate/ requestLocationUpdates() called
D/IndoorAtlasActivity: onResume/ requestLocationUpdates() called
D/IACore: IndoorAtlas Android SDK
           SDK    : 2.0.2-beta-9999
           Android: 4.2.1-17
           Date   : Sat, 20 Feb 2016 22:14:41 GMT
```

My `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `Activity`:

```
  public class IndoorAtlasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "IndoorAtlasActivity";

    private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
    private IAResourceManager mResourceManager;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private IATask<IAFloorPlan> mPendingAsyncResult = null;

    private IAResourceManager mFloorPlanManager;
    private IAFloorPlan mFloorPlan;
    private long mDownloadId;
    private DownloadManager mDownloadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_indooratlas);

        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        mIALocationManager.registerRegionListener(mRegionListener);

        mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mLocationListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate/ requestLocationUpdates() called");

        mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);
        mFloorPlanManager = IAResourceManager.create(this);

        /* optional setup of floor plan id
           if setLocation is not called, then location manager tries to find
           location automatically */
        final String floorPlanId = "my_floor_plan_id";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(floorPlanId)) {
            final IALocation location = IALocation.from(IARegion.floorPlan(floorPlanId));
            mIALocationManager.setLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mLocationListener);
        mIALocationManager.registerRegionListener(mRegionListener);
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume/ requestLocationUpdates() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mIALocationManager.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationListener);
        mIALocationManager.unregisterRegionListener(mRegionListener);
        unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause/ removing requestLocationUpdates()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mIALocationManager.destroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy/ destroying mIALocationManager");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private IALocationListener mLocationListener = new IALocationListenerSupport() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
        }
    };

    private IARegion.Listener mRegionListener = new IARegion.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onEnterRegion(IARegion region) {
            if (region.getType() == IARegion.TYPE_FLOOR_PLAN) {
                String id = region.getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "floorPlan changed to " + id);
                Toast.makeText(IndoorAtlasActivity.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fetchFloorPlan(id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitRegion(IARegion region) {
            // leaving a previously entered region
        }

    };

    /*  Broadcast receiver for floor plan image download */
    private BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0L);
            if (id != mDownloadId) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Ignore unrelated download");
                return;
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "Image download completed");
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
            Cursor c = mDownloadManager.query(q);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    // process download
                    String filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(
                            DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                    showFloorPlanImage(filePath);
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
    };

    private void showFloorPlanImage(String filePath) {
        Log.w(TAG, "showFloorPlanImage: " + filePath);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(filePath)
                .into(mImageView);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches floor plan data from IndoorAtlas server. Some room for cleaning up!!
     */
    private void fetchFloorPlan(String id) {
        cancelPendingNetworkCalls();
        final IATask<IAFloorPlan> asyncResult = mFloorPlanManager.fetchFloorPlanWithId(id);
        mPendingAsyncResult = asyncResult;
        if (mPendingAsyncResult != null) {
            mPendingAsyncResult.setCallback(new IAResultCallback<IAFloorPlan>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(IAResult<IAFloorPlan> result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "fetch floor plan result:" + result);
                    if (result.isSuccess() && result.getResult() != null) {
                        mFloorPlan = result.getResult();
                        String fileName = mFloorPlan.getId() + ".img";
                        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + fileName;
                        File file = new File(filePath);
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            DownloadManager.Request request =
                                    new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mFloorPlan.getUrl()));
                            request.setDescription("IndoorAtlas floor plan");
                            request.setTitle("Floor plan");
                            // requires android 3.2 or later to compile
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.
                                        Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
                            }
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.
                                    DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

                            mDownloadId = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
                        } else {
                            showFloorPlanImage(filePath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // do something with error
                        if (!asyncResult.isCancelled()) {
                            Toast.makeText(IndoorAtlasActivity.this,
                                    (result.getError() != null
                                            ? "error loading floor plan: " + result.getError()
                                            : "access to floor plan denied"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, Looper.getMainLooper()); // deliver callbacks in main thread
        }
    }

    private void cancelPendingNetworkCalls() {
        if (mPendingAsyncResult != null && !mPendingAsyncResult.isCancelled()) {
            mPendingAsyncResult.cancel();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an imageview for the floor plan to be loaded and displayed. You need a class called "BlueDotView" which you can find from this link: [BlueDotView class](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/imageview/BlueDotView.java). If you go through the **ImageViewActivity** class properly (from where you created the activity), you will see that there is no such imageview which needs to be used. The ImageViewActivity class has the following: 
**private BlueDotView mImageView;**.

In order to properly load the floor plan, perform the following steps. 
 1. Properly cross-check your activity with the **ImageViewActivity**. 
 2. You must have the BlueDotView class as a separate class. 
 3. In your activity_indooratlas XML file, you should have something as below which is from the github repository of the SDK 2.0 and not what you have in your XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.imageview.BlueDotView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

4. Make sure you have api key and api secret key from the IndoorAtlas website and included in your android manifest file. Check android manifest from github repository, here is the link: [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: I've copied `BlueDotView` class and `ImageViewActivity` from sample, but still have white screen without map :(

Comment: Have you uploaded the floor plan on  the IndoorAtlas website and have you done any kind of mapping process? If your answer is yes then check your android manifest as well as remove what you have in your activity_indooratlas xml file and replace it with my code which I have provided in the answer above. In that XML code, you need to use your own package name which will subsequently end with **Yourpackagename.BlueDotView**.  You can get more help from this link: http://docs.indooratlas.com/android/

Comment: I have uploaded .png on IndoorAtlas server, but I haven't done mapping process. I thought code in the sample loads .png image from server.

Comment: Maybe do some mapping, and maybe it could help you get the map in your app.

Comment: Ok. I will try to mapping. Thank you for help